# Upgrading to NHibernate 3.1: Bug with LINQ, Any and mapped component collections

Tags: nhibernate

We are currently upgrading from NHibernate 2 to 3.1. The following scenario worked with the old LINQ provider but doesn't work with the new provider in NHibernate 3.1.

Here is the mapping for the scenario:

```
public class FooDbMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooDbMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        HasMany(x => x.Bars)
            .Component(part =>
                {
                    part.Map(y => y.Name);
                })
            .KeyColumn("FooId")
            .Table("FooBars");
    }
}
```

NHibernate correctly generates the schema from the above mapping:

```
create table Foo (
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null
)

create table FooBars (
    FooId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
    Name TEXT not null,
    primary key (FooId, Name)
)
```

However, the following query generates an error:

```
Session.Query<Foo>()
    .Where(foo => foo.Bars.Any())
    .ToList();
```

The error is:
*System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Invalid column name 'Id'.*

The SQL that NHibernate has generated is:

```
select foo0_.Id as Id20_
from Foo foo0_
where exists (select bar1_.Id from Bar bar1_
              where foo0_.Id = bar1_.FooId)
```

Almost right, but not quite - at the last minute NHibernate gets it wrong and decides that there should be an Id column on the Bar table.

This problem didn't used to occur with the old Linq-to-Nhibernate provider.

I can think of a few workarounds, but is this an NHibernate bug or feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug. You can vote here: [NH-2692](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2692)

Answer (score 1):

Bug is still present in NHibernate 3.3.3.

As a workaround, you can use `.Count() > 0`:

```
Session.Query<Foo>()
    .Where(foo => foo.Bars.Count() > 0)
    .ToList();
```