# Bug generating SQL with NHibernate, Bag and Enumerable.Any()?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I'm facing the following situation.

My objectmodel is as follows:

```
EntityA --*> EntityB -> EntityC
```

`EntityA` references a list of `EntityB`. `EntityB` references a single `EntityC`

My mapping is:

```
  <class name="EntityA" table="TAB_A" >
    <id name="Id" column="A_ID" >
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <version name="Version" column="VERSION" />
    <bag name="listOfB" cascade="save-update" table="A_TO_C" lazy="false" >
      <key column="FK_A_ID" />

      <composite-element class="EntityB" >
        <many-to-one name="refToC" class="EntityC" column="FK_C_ID" cascade="save-update" />
      </composite-element>
    </bag>
  </class>
```

I left out all the extra properties and stuff.

I query the DB:

```
var query = session.Query<EntityA>()
                    .Where(a=> a.listOfB.Any(b => b.refToC == anInstanceOfC));

// count all matches
var count = query.ToFutureValue(t => t.Count());
```

Okay, that looks good for me so far ;). When I execute the query I get an error, that an SQL-Statement fails. The generated SQL contains the following sub statement:

```
select listOfB1_.A_ID
from A_TO_C listOfB1_
where a0_.A_ID=listOfB1_.FK_A_ID
and listOfB1_.FK_C_ID=?
```

The statement expects a column A_ID on table A_TO_C (which actually is the column name of the id-column of TAB_A). What it should do, is selecting the column listOfBl_.FK_A_ID wich is the foreign-key-column referencing the A_ID column of TAB_A.

Now the question: Am I wrong or is it the SQL-generator ?

Comment: Do you have a Primary Key setup for Table A, also Secondary Key or Foreign Key for the other tow tables A being the Primary Key

Comment: Actually I don't care :D. But NHibernate generated the primary key A_ID for TAB_A and C_ID for TAB_C. The foreign-keys are defined on columns FK_A_ID and FK_C_ID. That worked as i expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is a bug.

See [another thread on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032453/upgrading-to-nhibernate-3-1-bug-with-linq-any-and-mapped-component-collections),

my question and [discussion on the nhibernate googlegroup](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/fed9715eeb45d8e0%20)

and [the actual bug report](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2692) in the nhibernate issue tracker